# Opening Google Play from my application to list all my apps: Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I know How to open Google play store direct from my application with an application package name. But, I want to list all my application available in Play store. I searched a lot for the same but I didn't found any resolution for my problem.

For opening a particular application we need to pass package name to the `Intent`. So I think we'll have to pass developer ID to list all applications. Please help me to display my application available on Google Play. Your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate with you browser to your play account: f.e

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=XY
```

and open this url with an intent:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=XY");
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Comment: Is it possible to open it with Google Play app?

Answer (score 1):

```
    String url = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.my_app";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

The play store will open in the browser, but the user will still be unable to download and install, as his/her device won't show up as valid in the list of play store devices that it can be installed on (remember that the browser version of the play store never downloads, but instead just sends it via cloud installing to various devices). Your only option would be, if there is no play store installed, to offer them a download link for sideloading.

Answer (score 1):

this is appropriate one

```
final String dev_name= "DEVELOPER NAME";
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q="+dev_name)));
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id="+dev_name)));
            }
```